# SQL XML - exist: is there a better way?

Tags: sql, xml, rdbms

We use an XML column alongside traditional columns in a couple of tables in our SQL Server 2008 R2 database with the structure as follows:

```
<bridging>
  <project id="43" source="true" />
  <project id="48" source="false" />
  <project id="99" source="false" />
  <project id="123" source="false" />
</bridging>
```

Then, we select data from these tables using stored procs with a .exist XPath query in the WHERE clause, as follows:

```
SELECT  
    e.ID, 
    e.ProjectsBridge,
    e.Quantity, 
    e.Rate, 
    e.UOMID, 
    u.Name as UOM
FROM    
    tblEstimator e LEFT OUTER JOIN
    tblUnitOfMeasure u ON u.ID = e.UOMID
WHERE   
    (e.ProjectsBridge.exist('//bridging/project/@id[. = sql:variable("@ProjectID")]') = 1 OR 
     @ProjectID IS NULL)
```

This works very well on a smaller dataset, but the bigger the dataset, the slower this gets - the above example running well over 2 minutes on a dataset of a million-odd records.

So the question is whether there is a better, faster way to do this query?

Would applying an XML schema to the column make a significant difference?

Comment: I don't know how big the Xml documents you have in the database are but from XPath point of view descendant-or-self axis (i.e. '//') is one of the costliest operations. Try changing your XPath to '/bridging/project[@id = sql:variable("@ProjectID")]' and see if this speed things up a little bit. I don't know if using schema can speed things up but my gut feeling is that it won't. I suspect it just prevents from inserting to the database documents that are not valid according to the schema.

Comment: I have tried applying a schema, and that makes hardly any difference, and changing the XPath as above gains me 1 second on 138, so no gain really to speak of.  Thanks for the reply though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things that you can try:

- Add an index to your XML column: [Indexes on XML Data Type Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191497%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)
- Use a computed column: [Using XML in Computed Columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510426%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Also a CROSS APPLY may be more efficient in your context:

```
SELECT e.ID 
FROM tblEstimator e
CROSS APPLY e.ProjectsBridge.nodes('/bridging/project') AS T(c)
WHERE T.c.value('@id', 'INT') = @ProjectId
```

Comment: Thanks Nip for the comprehensive response - I'm going through these one by one.  So far, the CROSS APPLY (which I had to change to an OUTER APPLY because it's not a straight join) saves me 4 seconds on 138 - not a major saving.  Will report back on the other options once I've tried them out.  Thanks again!

Comment: Adding a primary XML index cuts the query execution down to 47 seconds - a saving of 63%!!!  Incidentally, the '/bridging/project[@id' XPath runs twice as long here as '//bridging/project/@id[.'.

Comment: Adding secondary XML indices increases the execution time back up to 127 seconds on '//bridging/project...', 92 seconds for '/bridging/project...'.  Not useful either.  So so far it's primary XML indices FTW!  Just computed columns left to try...

Comment: So obviously computed columns wouldn't work in this context, because we want to select where a specific id (in possibly multiple <project> node rows, with differing id values) is equal to the @ProjectID parameter.  So in our application, primary XML indices is the answer - thanks again Nip!

Comment: Turns out SQL creates Primary and Secondary indexes on XML columns by default - my solution was to just remove *all* secondary XML indices from the database.